# Export R list into Matlab cell-array

Tags: r, matlab

I have searched everywhere and I'm currently unable to find a solution to my issue.

I have a list created under Rstudio which is made of matrices `list(mat1,mat2,...)`.
What i would like to do is export that list to matlab to get a cell-array with each cell containing 1 matrix. 
Does anyone has any idea how to proceed ? I have used the `R.matlab` package already but when I import the resulting file in matlab I obtain a "structure" file which seems to be empty. following is my code to export.

`W1` is my list.

```
library('R.matlab')
writeMat("W1.mat",W1export=W1)
```

Thanks

Comment: try this work flow. create a cell array in matlab, then store the data as `.mat` format. Now read `.mat` file into R using `readMat` and learn the structure of the imported data using `str`. Now convert it back to `.mat` using `writeMat` function and import it in matlab. By following it, you will understand how it works.